# Automapper custom resolvers

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I am sorry for my simple question but I can't get it to work .
My problem:
I want to map from domain Object to Model Object but,
In domain object I have a list so my object look like:

```
public class Conference
 {
   public virtual  int Id{get;set;}
   public virtual int  NumberOfTables{get;set;}
   public virtual IList<People> Peoples{get;set;}
 }

public class People
 {
   public virtual  int Id{get;set;}
   public virtual string FirstName{get;set;}
   public virtual string LastName{get;set;}
   public virtual  Conference Conference{get;set;}
 }

My model :


public class Model
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public int NumberOfTables{get;set;}
  public string Peoples{get;set;}
}
```

I want People to be like :"FirstName"+"LastName"+"," for all people from list
Now on mapping from Domain Obj To Model I have something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Conference,Model>()
     .ForMember(c => c.Id, op => op.MapFrom(v => v.Id))
     .ForMember(c => c.NumberOfTables, op => op.MapFrom(v => v.NumberOfTables))
      .ForMember(c => c.Peoples, op => op//here I want to use ResolveUsing or something like this  )



  public class CustomConvert: ValueResolver<IList<GroupOfComponentInComplexToMeal>, string>
    {
        protected override string ResolveCore(IList<People> source)
        {
            string result = "";
            if (source.Any())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
                {
                    var name=source[i].FirstName+source[i].LastName;
                    result += name;
                    if (i < source.Count - 1)
                    {
                        result += ",";
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I did this CustomConvert but I can't merge it with my mapper.

I really don't now if I need to use Custom converters but I want to learn how they work.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was really simple to get it to work but I still need some good examples to learn more about Custom resolvers.

**Solution:**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Conference,Model>()
    .ForMember(c => c.Id, op => op.MapFrom(v => v.Id))
    .ForMember(c => c.NumberOfTables, op => op.MapFrom(v => v.NumberOfTables))
    .ForMember(c => 
        c.Peoples, op => op.ResolveUsing<CustomConvert>().FromMember(x => x.Peoples)
    );
```